# Iterate through dependent getjson() calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to perform the following actions at a high level:

- Make an API call to generate an array of cardIDs for a Trello board
- Iterate and make an API call for each cardID, pull some action (history) data for each card and store that in the action_tableData table
- Once complete, append action_tableData to the table object

The way I understand things is that I need to perform a getJSON call, let that finish and then perform another getJSON on top of that. I've looked around and understand the $.when() function might help, but I can't seem to even remotely make that work.

I think there could be an issue when the getJSON returns an undefined object, but I'm not sure how to skip those. Any help would be most appreciated!

```
cardIDapiCall = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/" + boardID + "/cards?fields=id&key=" + appKey + "&token=" + tokenKey;
        $.getJSON(cardIDapiCall, function(cardID) {
            var cardID_tableData = [];

            // Iterate over the JSON object
            for (var i = 0, len = cardID.length; i < len; i++) {
                cardID_tableData.push({
                    "card_id": cardID[i].id,
                });
            }

            //get action data
            for (var j = 1, len = cardID_tableData.length; j < len; j++) {

                //this alert works
                alert("card id: " + cardID_tableData[j].card_id);

                var actionapiCall = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + cardID_tableData[j].card_id + "/actions?key=" + appKey + "&token=" + tokenKey;   


                //why isn't this getting called???
                $.getJSON(actionapiCall, function() {
                    //this alert doesn't work
                    alert("action call successful");
                });
                    var action_tableData = [];

                    action_tableData.push({
                        "action_id": action[j].id,
                        "action_type": action[j].type,
                    })

                table.appendRows(action_tableData);
                doneCallback();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you've solved your problem now?

Comment: I haven't been able to fix this yet, no

Comment: To my understanding the way to do this is using your callbacks. Depending on how many functions deep you need to go, you can embed them (Beware callback hell) or else pass in a callback function you've defined elsewhere. This will ensure that the next action isn't complete until the function before it is complete.

Comment: Is it necessary that you've called `$.getJSON` callback from inside another `$.getJSON` callback in this case?